# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed / FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: c++, json, node.js, ubuntu, memory-management

I installed node on an ubuntu server and am trying to run a basic node program from the server. In it, I try to read in 13 json files, ranging from 120mb - 500+ mb. Previously, I was running it locally, which was ok for the smaller files but was running into the following error when trying to read the larger ones:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I need to be able to parse through the json object after reading the file, so I can't read it line by line. And I need to be able to build a cumulative object from the results of parsing all the objects. Like I said, the code works just fine and produces the result I expect when handling 3+ smaller files (< 20mb), but crashes with the larger ones.

When trying to run it on the server, I have the same issue (it'll work just fine with smaller files), but crashes with the following error on larger ones:

```
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, line 48
# CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: V8_Fatal
 2: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)
 3: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding)
 4: node::Buffer::Utf8Slice(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
 5: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))
 6: ??
 7: ??
[1]    12381
```

illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  node main2.js

This is the code chunk it's failing in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonFileArray.length; i++) {
    if (jsonFileArray[i].match(/\.json$/)) {
      jsonObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dirPath + jsonFileArray[i]));
      categoryListObject = jsonManipulator.getFieldValues("Categories", jsonObject, categoryListObject);
    }
}
```

I tried increasing my --max-old-space-size, but that didn't help. Also, I should clarify, I'm pretty new to coding and have never written anything in C, so despite googling this, I'm not really sure where to go next. So really, any help/guidance/insight/step in the right direction would be super appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Go with the debugger ...

Comment: For large jsons I suggest using SAX like parsers, the idea is to not load whole file in memory but iterate its content.

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing an entire huge JSON file into memory so this can be expected. Try using something like this module: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream and read the files with a read stream (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options).

Comment: I added JSONStream and tried simply logging the data before doing anything more complicated, but it still eventually gave me the error: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Comment: Remove all your logic and see can you simply stream a single file from start to finish, logging it chunk by chunk to the console. Maybe update the answer with the JSON stream code?